# Equicontinuous point wise convergence proof

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Problem:

Let $(f_n)_n\subseteq C[0,1]$ be equicontinuous. Further suppose for each $t\in [0,1]$, $f_n(t)$ converges to a real number, $f(t)$. Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly in  $C[0,1]$.

My attempt:
It suffices to show that $f_n$ is Cauchy:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $\{t_1,......,t_n...\}$ be a dense subset of $[0,1]$.

Thus if $t\in [0,1]$, we may find by equicontinuity, some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|t-u|<\delta$ then $|f_n(t)-f_n(u)|<\epsilon$ for all n. In particular, we may choose some $k$ such that $|t-t_k|<\delta$. As $f_n(t_k)$ converges, there exists some $N$ such that whenever $n,m>N$, we must have $|f_n(t_k)-f_m(t_k)|<\epsilon$. Thus whenever $n,m>N$, we must have $|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|\leq |f_n(t)-f_n(t_k)|+|f_n(t_k)-f_m(t_k)|+|f_m(t_k)-f_m(t)|<3\epsilon$.

Thus $f_n$ is Cauchy with respect to the uniform norm. Thus by completeness the result follows.

**Is my proof correct**?

Comment: Can you use Arzela-Ascoli?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro no, but how would you use it?

Comment: Also, your proof is not good. You need to find to show that for $m,n$ sufficiently large and **independently of $t$**, you have $|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|$ small. But your $N$ (which determines the "sufficiently large" part) depends on $k$, which in turn depends on $t$.

Comment: By Arzela-Ascoli (this version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces), there is a subsequence of the $f_n$ which converges uniformly, and the uniform limit obviously needs to be $f$. I'm not sure how you could get rid of the 'subsequence' part without going through the usual proof of Arzela-Ascoli, but perhaps it is feasible.

Comment: Notice that compactness of the domain, which you have not used in your solution, is necessary: Take, for example, $f_n(x)=\max(0,x-n)$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the $f_n$ are (uniformly) equicontinuous, as $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq|x-y|$ for all $x,y$, $f_n\to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro thank you! that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of solving this is going more-or-less through the proof of Arzela-Ascoli.

Use compactness of $[0,1]$ and equicontinuity to prove that the family is actually *uniformly equicontinuous*: For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Take $\delta$ as above. By compactness of $[0,1]$, take points $t_1,\ldots,t_k$ such that for every $x\in[0,1]$, there exists $i$ such that $|x-t_i|<\delta$. Then take $N$ such that if $n>N$, we have $|f_n(t_i)-f(t_i)|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$ and any $i=1,\ldots,k$.

Given $x\in[0,1]$, choose $i$ with $|x-t_i|<\delta$. Then $|f_n(x)-f_n(t_i)|<\epsilon$ for all $n$, so taking $n\to\infty$ yields $|f(x)-f(t_i)|\leq\epsilon$. Thus, for $n>N$,
$$|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq |f(x)-f(t_i)|+|f(t_i)-f_n(t_i)|+|f_n(t_i)-f_n(x)|<3\epsilon.$$

Comment: That makes so much sense, thanks !